# DER-Encoding of ASN.1 Types

Tags: encoding, certificate, x509certificate, asn.1, der

I'm having trouble finding some explaination on how to encode/decode various types in Distinguished Encoding Rules. How are strings (IA5String, PrintableString) and time (UTCTime, GeneralTime) encoded?

Answer (score 2):

I found very useful the ASN.1 Complete [book](http://www.oss.com/asn1/resources/books-whitepapers-pubs/larmouth-asn1-book.pdf) by Prof. John Larmouth.